# Adding legend in geopandas plot with subplots changes size of plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, legend, geopandas

I want to plot two GeoPandas plots with matplotlib subplots. The two maps have the same legend, and therefore I only want to have one legend. However, if I add a legend to one of the GeoPandas plots, the plot becomes slightly smaller. This is a problem since the two plots then become different sizes.

Here is my code:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12,8))
sealand_grid.plot(column=sealand_grid['p_2012'], 
                  ax=ax[0],
                  cmap='magma')
sealand_grid.plot(column=sealand_grid['p_2013'], 
                  ax=ax[1],
                  cmap='magma', 
                  legend=True,
                  legend_kwds={'shrink': 0.3})
ax[0].set_title('Housing prices 2012', fontsize=18)
ax[1].set_title('Housing prices 2013', fontsize=18)
fig.patch.set_facecolor('xkcd:white')
ax[0].axis('off')
ax[1].axis('off')
fig.tight_layout()
```

where `sealand_grid` is my GeoPandas-dataframe, and `p_2012` and `p_2013` are the variables plotted in the two maps.

**How do I get the two maps to be the same size, while only having one legend?**

[image: the resulting plot looks like this]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to reproduce you issue, I used this code, which basically shows the same result: the image on the right is slightly smaller than the left one due to the colorbar.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

D2012 = np.random.rand(10, 10)
D2013 = np.random.rand(10, 10)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize = (16,8))

P2012 = ax1.imshow(D2012,
             cmap = 'magma')
P2013 = ax2.imshow(D2013,
             cmap = 'magma')

ax1.set_title('2012', fontsize = 18)
ax2.set_title('2013', fontsize = 18)
ax1.axis('off')
ax2.axis('off')
plt.colorbar(P2013)

plt.show()
```

which gives this plot:

[image]

I solved with this turnaround:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

D2012 = np.random.rand(10, 10)
D2013 = np.random.rand(10, 10)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize = (16,8))
ax3 = fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.1, 0.1, 0.8])

P2012 = ax1.imshow(D2012,
             cmap = 'magma')
P2013 = ax2.imshow(D2013,
             cmap = 'magma')

ax1.set_title('2012', fontsize = 18)
ax2.set_title('2013', fontsize = 18)
ax1.axis('off')
ax2.axis('off')
ax3.axis('off')
plt.colorbar(P2013, ax = ax3)

plt.show()
```

which gives this plot:

[image]

Basically, I add a third axis, turn it off and add to it the colorbar. You need to pay attention to the position of this third axis with the parameters inside the method: `fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.1, 0.1, 0.8])`.
I know this is not the most elegant solution, for sure.

---

**EDIT**

A more robust and elegant solution is to keep 2 axes, but set their size and position when you define them:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

D2012 = np.random.rand(10, 10)
D2013 = np.random.rand(10, 10)

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (16,8))
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0, 0.2, 0.6, 0.6])
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.4, 0.2, 0.6, 0.6])

P2012 = ax1.imshow(D2012,
             cmap = 'magma')
P2013 = ax2.imshow(D2013,
             cmap = 'magma')

ax1.set_title('2012', fontsize = 18)
ax2.set_title('2013', fontsize = 18)
ax1.axis('off')
ax2.axis('off')
plt.colorbar(P2013)

plt.show()
```

which gives this plot:

[image]

In this case you have to pay attention to the position and the size of the two axis with these lines:

```
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0, 0.2, 0.6, 0.6])
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.4, 0.2, 0.6, 0.6])
```

Comment: Thanks! Your first suggestion do not solve the problem, as I am adding the colorbar from the geopandas plot, and not from the matplotlib package. However, your EDIT with specifying the size of the axes when initializing the subplots did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to create an exclusive axes for plotting the color bar. So 3 axes are created for 2 required plots. Note the use of `gridspec_kw` with proper values of `width_ratios` to obtain required widths of the subplots. Here is the runnable code and the resulting plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create simple data for demo plot
data = np.arange(100, 0, -1).reshape(10, 10)

# figsize plays important role; must set it wide enough
# here 3 axes are created
# the width ratio of the 3rd axes must be small to get good result (here = 0.03)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(9.5, 4), gridspec_kw={"width_ratios":[0.4535, 0.4535, 0.03]})

# first 2 axes are used to plot images
im0 = ax[0].imshow(data, cmap='bone')
im1 = ax[1].imshow(data, cmap='bone')

# The third axes, ax[2] is exclusive to the color bar
# When cax id specified, 'shrink' and 'aspect' properties are ignored
cb = fig.colorbar(im0, cax=ax[2], orientation='vertical')

plt.show()
```

With this approach, the color bar can be placed on any of the 3 axes, but you have to change the code accordingly to get it done.

[image]

Comment: @ Andrea Blengino How can you say they are the same. The outcome? No, the approach is the code not the outcome. And I am considering to vote you up. Now I must wait for a while. Your answer is good no reason not doing so.