# Two confusion matrix plots have different sizes

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to plot to confusion matrix in the same image, but they come out in different sizes.

Here's the code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize = (18,8))
fig.suptitle('Matriz de Confusão')


skplt.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_log, normalize=True, ax=ax[0], title=('Regressão Logística'))
skplt.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_tree, normalize=True, ax=ax[1], title=('Árvore de decisão'))
ax[0].xaxis.set_ticklabels(['Normal', 'Fraude']); ax[0].yaxis.set_ticklabels(['Normal', 'Fraude']);
ax[1].xaxis.set_ticklabels(['Normal', 'Fraude']); ax[1].yaxis.set_ticklabels(['Normal', 'Fraude']);


plt.show()
```

And this is what I'm getting:
[image]

How can I change the size of the second plot?
Also if I could delete the extra color bar would be nice.

Comment: Try `ax = ax.ravel()` after `fig, ax = ...` and see what happens. Though I can't reproduce this issue in `matplotlib 3.4.3`

Comment: `plot_confusion_matrix` has the parameter `colorbar=False`, however, removing the color bar will change the size of the matrix, which is also why your two plots axes are different sizes. One has no color bar and one has two, so the API resized them. Since this doesn't contain a complete [mre], it's not reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sould define the axes where colorbar need to be placed. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62308379/9214357) as a reference.
Applying those concept to your case would result in something similar to this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


M1 = np.random.rand(2, 2)
M2 = np.random.rand(2, 2)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize = (18, 8))
plt.subplots_adjust(right = 0.77)
cbar_ax_1 = fig.add_axes([0.8, 0.1, 0.04, 0.8])
cbar_ax_2 = fig.add_axes([0.9, 0.1, 0.04, 0.8])

im_1 = ax[0].imshow(M1, cmap = 'magma')
im_2 = ax[1].imshow(M2, cmap = 'magma')

plt.colorbar(im_1, cax = cbar_ax_1)
plt.colorbar(im_2, cax = cbar_ax_2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

If you want one colorbar only, it is wiser to normalize the unique colorbar based on both matrices' values:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
from matplotlib import cm


M1 = np.random.rand(2, 2)
M2 = np.random.rand(2, 2)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize = (18, 8))
plt.subplots_adjust(right = 0.87)
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.9, 0.1, 0.04, 0.8])
norm = Normalize(vmin = min(np.min(M1), np.min(M2)), vmax = max(np.max(M1), np.max(M2)))
cmap = cm.magma

im_1 = ax[0].imshow(M1, cmap = cmap)
im_2 = ax[1].imshow(M2, cmap = cmap)

plt.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(norm = norm, cmap = cmap), cax = cbar_ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]